# Syntax for Id'ing if Access DB was open by user or programmatically

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm Looking for the syntax for Id'ing if Access DB was open by user or programmatically. I have seen it before and can't find it now. It was just a simple one line function that has a boolean output. Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read into `Application.UserControl` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/application-usercontrol-property-access). It does exactly what you want.

Note that it isn't a ReadOnly property, and I tend to set it to true to make sure Access doesn't close when the program that opened it quit.

Comment: Yep, this was it. Thank you for your answer.